# Is there any way to compile a project with CocoaPods with ENABLE_BITCODE=YES?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, cocoapods

When I try it, compilation fails with this error: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle cannot be used together...

I get the error when I try to compile my iOS app with ENABLE_BITCODE=YES. I know that settings ENABLE_BITCODE=NO would work, but this also means that I cannot submit my app to the AppStore.

I wonder how anyone has been able to submit iOS9 apps to the AppStore when this issue pretty much makes it impossible for any decent app using CocoaPods.

Comment: Just in case: Yes, I have cleaned my project. Yes I have updated CocoaPods. Yes I have cleaned Derived Data.